# react update state inside custom hook, but didn't return update value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i'm trying to create a component which uses sort of stepbar, and this stepbar needs some data ( like current step, methods for change steps etc. )

I am creating a custom hook with all these methods

```
export const useSteps = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const orderId = useSelector(getCheckinOrderId);
    const checkinHasStarted = useSelector(getCheckinHasStarted);
    const hasMeals = useSelector(hasMealServices);
    const hasBaggage = useSelector(hasBaggageServices);
    const { t } = useTranslation('Checkin');
    const steps: Steps = {
        findBooking: {
            label: t('Find booking')
        },
        baggage: {
            isHidden: !hasBaggage,
            label: t('Baggage')
        },
        meal: {
            isHidden: !hasMeals,
            label: t('Meal')
        },
        seats: {
            label: t('Seats')
        },
        payment: {
            label: t('Payment')
        },
        boardingPass: {
            label: t('Boarding pass')
        }
    };

    const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(
        Object.keys(steps).findIndex(stepKey => history.location.pathname.includes(stepKey))
    );

    const updateActiveStep = () => {
        setActiveStep(Object.keys(steps).findIndex(stepKey => history.location.pathname.includes(stepKey)));
    };

    console.log(activeStep); // properly updates when updateActiveStep() called

    return {
        steps,
        activeStep,
        setStep: (step: CheckinStep) => {
            history.push(`/${orderId}/${step}`);
            updateActiveStep();
        },

        nextStep: (currentStep: CheckinStep, replace = false) => {
            // omitted next step logic

            updateActiveStep();
        },
        previousStep: (currentStep: CheckinStep, replace = false) => {
            //omitted prev step logic

            updateActiveStep();
        }
    };
};
```

but when i'm trying to get the `activeStep` variable inside my component in order to pass it to `<Stepbar />` component, i see that `activeStep` is always equal to the initial value

But inside my custom hook, `activeStep` is properly updated

I use this hook like so:

```
const Order: React.FC = () => {
    const isCheckinStarted = useSelector(getCheckinHasStarted);
    const isCheckinCompleted = useSelector(getCheckinHasCompleted);
    const hasBaggage = useSelector(hasBaggageServices);
    const hasMeals = useSelector(hasMealServices);

    const { steps, activeStep, nextStep, setStep } = useSteps();
    console.log(activeStep); // didn't udpate, always initial

    return (
        <div>
            <Stepbar variant="blue" steps={steps} />

            <Switch>
                <Route
                    path="/:id(\d+)"
                    exact
                    render={() => {
                        if (isCheckinStarted) {
                            nextStep(CheckinStep.Passengers, true);

                            return null;
                        }

                        return <Passengers />;
                    }}
                />

                <Route
                    path="/:id(\d+)/baggage"
                    render={() => {
                        if (isCheckinCompleted) {
                            nextStep(CheckinStep.Passengers, true);

                            return null;
                        }

                        if (!hasBaggage) {
                            nextStep(CheckinStep.Baggage, true);

                            return null;
                        }

                        return <Baggage />;
                    }}
                />

                <Route
                    path="/:id(\d+)/meal"
                    render={() => {
                        if (isCheckinCompleted) {
                            nextStep(CheckinStep.Passengers, true);

                            return null;
                        }

                        if (!hasMeals) {
                            nextStep(CheckinStep.Meal, true);

                            return null;
                        }

                        return <Meal />;
                    }}
                />

                <Route
                    path="/:id(\d+)/seats"
                    render={() => {
                        if (isCheckinCompleted) {
                            nextStep(CheckinStep.Passengers, true);

                            return null;
                        }

                        return <Seats />;
                    }}
                />

                <Route
                    exact
                    path="/:id(\d+)/payment"
                    render={() => {
                        if (isCheckinCompleted) {
                            nextStep(CheckinStep.Passengers, true);

                            return null;
                        }

                        return <Payment />;
                    }}
                />

                <Route
                    path="/:id(\d+)/payment/successfull"
                    render={() => {
                        if (isCheckinCompleted) {
                            nextStep(CheckinStep.Passengers, true);

                            return null;
                        }

                        return (
                            <PaymentResult
                                result="success"
                                onClick={reload => {
                                    if (reload) {
                                        location.reload();
                                    } else {
                                        setStep(CheckinStep.Passengers);
                                    }
                                }}
                            />
                        );
                    }}
                />

                <Route
                    path="/:id(\d+)/payment/failed"
                    render={() => {
                        if (isCheckinCompleted) {
                            nextStep(CheckinStep.Passengers, true);

                            return null;
                        }

                        return <PaymentResult result="fail" onClick={() => setStep(CheckinStep.Payment)} />;
                    }}
                />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
};
```

And I can't figure out why.

You can pay attention to lines with comments, other code works great.

Comment: You're not triggering `updateActiveStep()` anywhere in your component thus `activeStep` showing the initial value. you need to call `setStep()` in your component to trigger a state change.

Comment: @AliMousavi I'm trigger `updateActiveStep()` via `nextStep()` calls inside Order component. I just omit as much irrelevant code as i can ( in fact, value inside hook was changed, but not inside component )

Comment: You should include the codes in `Order` component related to the hook so we can see what's happening.

Comment: @AliMousavi ok, question was edited, i'll paste all Order.tsx content, exclude imports

Answer (score 0):

Something strange goes inside my hook, i'm print some debug info when initialize state

```
const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(() => {
  console.log('init for first time');

  return Object.keys(steps).findIndex(stepKey => 

  history.location.pathname.includes(stepKey));

});
```

when i'm change active step from parent component, i see this line (init for first time ) every time

```
const updateActiveStep = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('here');
    const newStep = Math.random();
    console.log('before set new step', newStep); // set random float 
    setActiveStep(newStep);
}, [activeStep]);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(activeStep, 'active step inside hook'); // always Int
}, [activeStep]);
```